# App Immediatley crashes once app runs with error ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class application on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Starting a new project and I am experiencing the following error... I have tried other solutions but seem to be dated

Steps I have tried:

- Double checked plugins (listed below)
- Instance Run (not listed)
- tried using kapt in-place of annotationProccessor (produces a different error)

```
    Process: com.example.transfer_tracker, PID: 28953
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.transfer_tracker.CoreApplication package com.example.transfer_tracker: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.transfer_tracker.CoreApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.transfer_tracker/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~zfKHJdy7wnPYBA_pfwtohQ==/com.example.transfer_tracker-gXT0kIH37Cwb7XaCDmovmg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~zfKHJdy7wnPYBA_pfwtohQ==/com.example.transfer_tracker-gXT0kIH37Cwb7XaCDmovmg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6686)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.transfer_tracker.CoreApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.transfer_tracker/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~zfKHJdy7wnPYBA_pfwtohQ==/com.example.transfer_tracker-gXT0kIH37Cwb7XaCDmovmg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~zfKHJdy7wnPYBA_pfwtohQ==/com.example.transfer_tracker-gXT0kIH37Cwb7XaCDmovmg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1177)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6686) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/transfer_tracker/Hilt_CoreApplication;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                ... 15 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.transfer_tracker.Hilt_CoreApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.transfer_tracker/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~zfKHJdy7wnPYBA_pfwtohQ==/com.example.transfer_tracker-gXT0kIH37Cwb7XaCDmovmg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~zfKHJdy7wnPYBA_pfwtohQ==/com.example.transfer_tracker-gXT0kIH37Cwb7XaCDmovmg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                ... 18 more
        [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/transfer_tracker/Hilt_CoreApplication;]
```

Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.transfer_tracker">

    <application
        android:name=".CoreApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TransferTracker">
        <activity
            android:name=".login.LauncherActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module project.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.transfer_tracker"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.40.5'
}
```

Application Class

```
package com.example.transfer_tracker

import android.app.Application
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class CoreApplication : Application()
```

when using kapt instead of annotationProccessor

```
public final class CoreApplication extends android.app.Application {
             ^
  Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? (dagger.hilt.android.plugin)
  See https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**UPDATE**

Implemented with Dagger2 error is gone... maybe this is due to a bug within the Hilt library

Comment: `tried using kapt in-place of annotationProccessor (produces a different error)` , What's that error?

Comment: Your error message mentions a `CIRCULAR REFERENCE` in Hilt regarding your Application class. Is it possible that you defined this class in the wrong place? Is your application class set in the `<application>` tag in the Manifest? Also double-check if your setup Multidex correctly. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: @muetzenflo I pasted the manifest code above and set multidex to true

Comment: just a wild guess. Could you try to remove the underscore from your package name: `transfertracker`?

Comment: Check your proguard's config.

Comment: @SujalKumar I have pasted the error when using kapt

Comment: @Darkman what should I check in proguard?

Comment: You can try disabling it temporary in your `project.gradle` (or comment it by putting a double slash in front of it) and see if it still produce an error. If it does, include the content of `proguard-rules.pro` in your question.

Comment: @Darkman no change in error

Comment: @muetzenflo resolved ```CIRCULAR REFERENCE```.. believe this was due to using midSDK 22 as multidexing is automatically enabled as of 21 (Android 5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Got it resolved by removing this from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    
      android:name="com.package.name.Application" <- Remove this entire line
```

Before that I tired invalidating caches, Project Clean, delete `build`, `.gradle` and `.idea` folders, upgraded everything to the latest versions.
Nothing else worked.

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted? What if we have a custom Application class?

Answer (score 2):

After adding these dependencies everything works fine

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the **CoreApplication** class with **MultiDexApplication** like this:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class CoreApplication : MultiDexApplication() {...}
```

Comment: I have tried this produces same error as above.. apologies should have mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

I think your Application class is getting saved in a different Dex file.

Trying to keep them in a single Dex file should work.

Try this [Procedure](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep)

Suggestion:

To check Dex file classes you can use Android Studio,
open your apk into Android Studio. You can see your dex files in the apk explorer.

Then select the dex file to see what classes are inside it.